# I want to enable Autocomplete when user select a value in select box and disable when user dis-select

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

1.I want to enable Auto-complete when user select a value in select box and disable when user dis-select

```
$("#selectorText").autocomplete({
   source: function (request, response) {
      $.getJSON("URL", {
         term: $('#selectorText').val();/this the select box value
      }, response);
   },
   minLength: 1,
   select: function (event, ui) {
       $(this).val(ui.item.value);
   }
});
```

2.This for default disable auto-complete when Page load

```
$( "#selectorText" ).autocomplete({
   disabled: true; //here is the code default disable
});
```

3. **now main logic start here, I want to enable Auto complete on special case suppose I have these values in select box {1,2,3,4,5}. and I want to enable auto complete when user select 3 and 4 other wise it will remain disable.**

```
$('#selctBox').change(function () {
    if(this.val()>0){
         $( "#selectorText" ).autocomplete({
         disabled: true
         });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the solution with you. Your code is fine, just change your condition little bit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //on page load

       $( "#selectorText" ).autocomplete( "disable" );

    // on selectbox change

    $('#selctBox').change(function () {
        if($(this).val() == 3 || $(this).val() == 4){
           $( "#selectorText" ).autocomplete( "enable" );
        } else {
           $( "#selectorText" ).autocomplete( "disable" );
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selctBox').change(function() {
    var this_val = $(this).val();
    if (3 <= this_val && this_val <= 4 ) {
        $("#selectorText").autocomplete("option", "disabled", false);
    }
    else { // 1,2,5
        $("#selectorText").autocomplete("option", "disabled", true);
    }
});
```